# Jupyter notebook upper/lowercase selected part

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I wonder if there are shortcut keys for converting the selected block into uppercase or lowercase letters.

For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> does this in Notepad++.

I searched

1. [this page listing shortcuts](https://towardsdatascience.com/jypyter-notebook-shortcuts-bf0101a98330)
2. and the manual in VS Code settings as in the screenshot

but I could not find it.

[image: VS Code Jupyter shortcut keys]

Comment: Long shot, but try Shift + F3?  That's what it is in Window's office software like Word.  As a workaround, you can also copy-paste into Word, do the conversion, then copy-paste it back.

Comment: @Arctiic Thank you for your comment, but it did not work..